# JQUERY UI Dialog with Site.css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-css-framework

Hello I am using jquery ui on a site I am working on. Two elements I use alot are the dialog and tab controls. I have a Site.css file that I apply custom styling as well as override some of the jquery ui css. Everything works as expected on standard pages. However if I place a jquery tab control inside a jquery dialog control, the tab control gets the default styling. Copying the tab code out to the main page (not in a dialog) the styling is applied properly.

For a test I added a  element to the dialog and applied a style with the Site.css and it worked fine.

Please help!

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the styles you're trying to customize.

Comment: jQuery UI moves the dialog markup to the bottom of the page on page load...this is possibly causing your selectors to be broke.

Comment: sounds like your tab style over ride rules aren't specific enough. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net with both versions of tabs for comparison